# Find c of linear combinations in non vector form?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$i + cj - 3k$ is a linear combination of $i + j$ and $j + 3k$.

How do I do this question, if it's not in vector form?

Should my approach be
$i + cj - 3k = a(i + j) + b(j + 3k)$?

Comment: Yes. Then find $a$ and $b$ which satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

$$\mathbf{i} + c\mathbf{j} - 3\mathbf{j} = a(\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j}) + b(\mathbf{j} + 3\mathbf{k})$$

you should solve for $a$ and $b$. You can say that all the coefficients of $\mathbf{i}$ on the right side should equal all the coefficients of $\mathbf{i}$ on the right side, same with $\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{k}$. This gives you a system of equations.

$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &= a\\
c &= a + b\\
-3 &= 3b\\
\end{aligned}
$$

This gives $a = 1, b = -1, c = 1 + -1 = 0$. So the linear combination we're talking about here is just negating the second vector and adding it to the first.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. We take $${\bf i} + c{\bf j} - 3{\bf k} = a({\bf i} + {\bf j}) + b({\bf j} + 3{\bf k}) = a{\bf i} + (a + b){\bf j} + 3b{\bf k}$$

We may equate coefficients to observe that $a = 1$ and $3b = -3 \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; b = -1$. So $c = a + b = 1 + (-1) = 0.$